# codeigniter session dies when it shouldn't

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, session

I have a website which requires you to log in. It makes use of codeigniter sessions. Here are the pages in context:
http://dancedric.fourthdraft.com/ 
and 
http://www.fourthdraft.com/index.php/frontend/index/dancedric

In order to show you the problem, you'll have to actually log in the system. user 'demo' (without quotes) as username and password. Now load the two links again.

They're the same page. the shorter one is just htaccess'd to redirect to the second link.

If you notice on the first link, upper right corner, it says "Login". On the second one, instead of login, it shows your name and shows you that you're already logged in.

My problem is that, they're the same page and on that corner, I have an if statement:
`if($this->session->userdata('xxx'))`  then show his/her name then control panel link; if not, just show 'login'.

I don't know if htaccess and mod_rewrite is interfering and terminating the session in the first link. I don't think the session is dead because even if it says 'login' on the first link, it still goes to your control panel when you click it even if it just says 'login'. I want the first link to work like the second. If the user is logged in, show his name etc. for some reason it's not working as planned...

Answer (score 0):

try setting `$config['cookie_domain'] = ""; to $config['cookie_domain'] = ".fourthdraft.com";` in `config.php`

Comment: doesn't work. It becomes worse. I get logged out on the second link too

Comment: hi, i think the problem is that you cant access cookie from outside another domain, for example you cant access www.fourthdraft.com session cookie from dancedric.fourthdraft.com

maybe try to set cookie domain to $config['cookie_domain'] = "fourthdraft.com";
*note the missing dot..

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work too. I really really appreciate the help.  What happens now is I can't log in anymore. It gets to my authentication script then it fails.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with my authentication practice right? if($this->session->userdata('xxx'))

either semantically or professionally? am i supposed to check sessions in a different way? 

Also, I tried retrieving the session manually through session_name then session_start but no luck.
I'm open to manual solutions as well

Comment: hi, i tested this on my server and it works.. maybe take a look..
the only thing you need to change is $config['cookie_domain'] to your top level domain...

note that user_model gets autoloaded..

almost forgot the link :]
http://www.megaupload.com/?d=6URXIFGV (contains codeigniter website)

hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, at the end was so obvious, the problem was in my htaccess, I was caching html, css, etc. If you put this at the end of your .htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c> 
<filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$"> 
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate" 
</filesMatch> 
</ifModule>
```

you'll get your session ok. This is because for example:

- You enter to your site, and you are not logged. But you already served a page view for users not logged in.
- Then you'll log in
- But when you return to your previous page, you'll see the same as previous page, as if you were not logged. This is because the browser show you the previous and cached page, even if your session exist...But if you reload you will see the correct page.